# Spring Integration AMQP - Wrong JSON type on Response

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I'm using Spring Integration & SI AMQP 3.0.0-RELEASE.

I have a fairly simple Request-Response over AMQP between two SI instances.

I'm finding that when the response arrives back on the requesting server, that SI is attempting to deserialize the response using the the Request object's type, not the Response object.

ie., Given the gateway interface of:

```
public AnalyticsReponse getAnalyticsReport(EntityMessage objectUri);
```

I find that even though the correct JSON of an `AnalyticsResponse` arrives on the server, SI is attempting to deserialize it as an `EntityMessage`, which is failing.

I've debugged it through, and I suspect that the cause is that the Responding side is copying the inbound `json__TypeId__` header, rather than supplying it's own.  However, I can't see where I've misconfigured this.

Here's my config -- what have I done wrong?

Requesting side:

```
<int:channel id="analytics.reports.requests.channel" /> 
<int:channel id="analytics.reports.responses.channel" />
<int:gateway service-interface="com.project.analytics.gateway.AnalyticsReportingGateway">
    <int:method name="getAnalyticsReport" request-channel="analytics.reports.requests.channel" reply-channel="analytics.reports.responses.channel"/>
</int:gateway>
<int-amqp:outbound-gateway 
    request-channel="analytics.reports.requests.channel" 
    reply-channel="analytics.reports.responses.channel"
    exchange-name="analytics.reports.exchange" amqp-template="amqpTemplate" />
```

Responding side:

```
<int:channel id="analytics.reports.requests.channel" /> 
<int:channel id="analytics.reports.responses.channel" />    
<int-amqp:inbound-gateway request-channel="analytics.reports.requests.channel" reply-channel="analytics.reports.responses.channel"
    queue-names="analytics.reports.queue" connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" message-converter="jsonMessageConverter"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="analytics.reports.requests.channel" output-channel="analytics.reports.responses.channel" 
    ref="analyticsReporter" method="getAnalytics"/>
<bean class="com.project.analytics.reporters.SimpleAnalyticsReporter" id="analyticsReporter"/>


public class SimpleAnalyticsReporter {

@SneakyThrows
public AnalyticsReponse getAnalytics(EntityMessage message) {
    return new AnalyticsReponse("Hello");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as you aren't interested in `org.springframework.integration.mapping.support.JsonHeaders`, because you use `jsonMessageConverter`, you should filter them (`<header-filter>`) or fully ignore all AMQP headers (`mapped-request-headers="-"` or `mapped-reply-headers="-"`).

However I see that I wasn't right yesterday (https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT-3285) and reopen the issue to revise how can we get deal with standard headers by default to allow to work similar scenarios.
Thank you!